# if and else both is being excuted

Tags: c, if-statement

I have strange problem with a simple c program.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
main() {
    int a, b, c, delta;
    float x1, x2;
    printf("Please Enter a,b,c :");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    delta = (b * b) - (4 * (a * c));
    if(delta < 0){
        printf("No roots!");
    } 
    else{
        if (delta >= 0){
            x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        }
    }
    printf("r1=%f and r2=%f", x1, x2);
    getch();

}
```

when I enter `2 1 1`, it seems, the program executes both `if` and `else` in line 10 and 13.
The output is `No roots!x1=0.0000 and x2=0.0000`
what's wrong?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: I Expected to see just no roots or the roots:) but I found my problem @ed-heal found it:))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
No roots!x1=0.0000 and x2=0.0000
```

If there are no roots you actually have **undefined behavior** because below

```
printf("r1=%f and r2=%f", x1, x2);
```

you are trying to print values of `x1` and `x2` - which are not initialized. And that line is executed regardless of `if` condition (due to the fact where you have put it in your code).

Why did you assume both `if` and `else` were executed?

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
  printf("r1=%f and r2=%f", x1, x2);
```

is not in the else clause. Also the `if (delta >= 0){` is not required. Change the code to

```
if(delta < 0) {
  printf("No roots!");
} 
else {
  x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
  x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
  printf("r1=%f and r2=%f", x1, x2);
}
getch();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not executing both `if` and `else`, what is happening is that `x1` and `x2` have to be printed out and their values are being printed out as `0` and `0`. I would recommend putting `printf("r1=%f and r2=%f", x1, x2);` inside the `else`. Also, i would recommend making `else { if` to be `else` because the `if` is unnecessary. Here is my recommendation

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
main() {
    int a, b, c, delta;
    float x1, x2;
    printf("Please Enter a,b,c :");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    delta = (b * b) - (4 * (a * c));
    if(delta < 0){
        printf("No roots!");
    } 
    else {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        printf("r1=%f and r2=%f", x1, x2);
    }

    getch();

}
```